# Magento category static block not getting displayed

Tags: php, magento

I am unable to make magento display static CMS block under category > display settings.

Contents of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` seem to be correct as per [similar question on SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16963/trying-to-display-static-block-for-category-will-only-display-category-view). Here you go:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have configured 3 categories, lets say

1. category_a (only products)
2. category_b (both products and cms)
3. category_c (only cms block).

Things I tried which don't work:

1. Disabled custom theme and used default theme of magento.
2. Replaced view.phtml from another magento installation (where its working fine).
3. Replace the if-else block with

   ```
   <?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
   MODE: CMS
       <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

   <?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
   MODE: MIXED
       <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
       <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

   <?php else: ?>
   MODE: PRODUCTS
       <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

   This displayed `MODE: PRODUCTS` for all 3 cases (product / cms / mixed)
4. Removing the if-else block and using only lines to force magento to display both cms and product blocks. Assuming the control was not flowing to correct block.

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>  
   <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
   ```

   Only product block got displayed for all 3 categories mentioned above (product / cms / mixed)
5. I can see that there are 2 problems here, or atleast I think so.

   1. category display mode is always coming as "products only"
   2. `getCmsBlockHtml()` does not return anything

so I tried following code snippet based on [Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View](http://freegento.com/doc/d7/d31/_catalog_2_block_2_category_2_view_8php-source.html)

```
Product: 
<?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode()==Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT; ?>
MIXED: 
<?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode()==Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_MIXED; ?>
CMS: 
<?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode()==Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PAGE; ?>
```

and got response as `>>Product: MIXED:1 CMS:` for all three category display modes (product / cms / mixed).

Can someone help me out please.
I have disabled caches and have tried reindexing also.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for my issue here
Magento 1.9.2.0

App/Code/Core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php
inside function getCmsBlockHtml

On Line 109 it read
return

but should read
return $this->getData('cms_block_html');

Regards paul